Setting the maximum for a cell
I’m trying to set the maximum value of a cell as the the value of another cell, so that the number in the original cell can’t exceed the second cell’s value.
For example, the equation for the first cell results in 40, but I want to set the maximum as 30 (the value from another cell), and make sure the first cell doesn’t exceed 30.
How do I do this, I’m not very experienced with google sheets, I only found out yesterday I can set certain values as the value of a separate cell and I’ve been going ham with it XD
What I Tried
=ROUNDDOWN(A1)>(B1)=MAX(B1)

(Round down because the value in A1 can be decimals and I want it to round down to the nearest whole number, which it does thankfully)
I expected this to set the cell to the value of B1 if A1 is a larger number than B1, but google sheets just says my formula is incorrect :(

Can you try this formula
=IF(ROUNDDOWN(A1) > B1, B1, "")
Breakdown
ROUNDDOWN(A1): This rounds down the value in A1 to the nearest whole number.

B1: This checks if the rounded-down value is greater than B1.
IF(...): This function returns B1 if the condition is true; otherwise, it returns an empty string (or you can replace "" with another value if needed).
You can place this formula in the cell where you want the result. If A1 is greater than B1 after rounding down, it will return the value of B1; otherwise, it will return nothing.


I solved it myself minutes after posting because I figured out how to use the IF() function.
=IF(A1>B1, B1, ROUNDDOWN(A1))
A1>B1 -> If A1 is larger than B1, then;
B1 -> if statement is TRUE;
ROUNDDOWN(A1) -> if statement is FALSE, rounded down (because I need that for the final number)
